# How to print a stack using a string, ended by a sentinel

Tags: java, string, stack

How do I get this to run? I have a stack, I push the String onto the stack, and I print the stack, do I have to also pop the stack to get this to run?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Stacks {
    public static void main(String args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String words;
        String DONE = null;
        Stack<String> series = new Stack<String>();
        System.out.println("Enter a series of words or 'DONE' to quit");
        words = input.nextLine();
        series.push(words);

        while (!words.equals("DONE")) {
            System.out.println(series);
            System.out.println("Enter a series of words or 'DONE' to quit");
            words = input.nextLine();

            if (words.equals("DONE")) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem with your code? Why do you only `push` once and not on each new word?

Comment: Do you have to `push` for each String? How's that plausible when the user is going to input a series of words?

Comment: Make the distinction between words and a `String`. Regardless of what you enter, `nextLine` returns everything (except the carriage return).

Comment: You can split at a delimiter or whitespace and handle pushing an array or List of elements in your own method or loop.